# Pointer to array of structs crashing upon inputting value

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I was learning about pointers,structures and AoS and the relation between them, I was trying to make a simple C code, that took input from users, using pointers. however, no matter what I try I have been running into Seg faults, for example in the code : the code crashes on every run as soon as I try to input the balance, if the code isnt correct, why is the exception not raised at the name or accno input, also what should be the right approach to do this task.

```
void input(struct bankacc b[],int n){
struct bankacc *ptr=NULL;
ptr=b;
for(;ptr<(b+n);ptr+=1)
{
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s",(ptr)->name);
    printf("Enter account number: ");
    scanf("%d",ptr->accno);
    printf("Enter balance: ");
    scanf("%f",ptr->balance);
    printf("_____ \n");        
}}
```

Image of code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JREvb.png

Comment: The `scanf("%d", ptr->accno);` should be `scanf("%d", &ptr->accno);` and `ptr->balance` too. Turn up the compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane that does work somehow but could you please explain why or how,or provide some source that does. tysm.

Comment: Because `ptr->accno` is the data value, not the address of the member which `scanf` function family needs. However `(ptr)->name` *decays* to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get the address of struct members:

```c
void input(struct bankacc b[],int n)
{
    struct bankacc *ptr=NULL;
    ptr = b;
    for(;ptr<(b+n);ptr+=1)
    {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", ptr->name);
        printf("Enter account number: ");
        scanf("%d", &(ptr->accno));
        printf("Enter balance: ");
        scanf("%f",&(ptr->balance));
        printf("_____ \n");        
    }
}
```

Comment: The `&` in `scanf("%s",&(ptr->name))` is at best unnecessary, and it might very well be flat wrong.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah you're write! It's not necessary thank you for your point!

Answer (score 0):

You have not presented the definition of `struct bankcc`, but presumably, its members `accno` and `balance` are an `int` and a `float`, respectively, not pointers to the same.  In that case, you need to pass `scanf` pointers to these, *e.g.* `scanf("%d",&ptr->accno)`.

Additionally, if the `name` member of `struct bankacc` is a (long enough) array of `char` or a pointer to a large enough space to accommodate the name that is entered then `scanf("%s",(ptr)->name)` is ok(-ish). But otherwise -- for example, if it is a `char *` that has not been assigned to point to any storage -- then that `scanf` is invalid, too.  You need to pass a valid pointer to a space large enough to receive the input.